# Same elements print as different font sizes despite styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble getting consistency with my print css in the same browser.

I'm trying to print a div that's centered by relative position and top: 40em.

**CSS**

```
 .wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    page-break-after: always;
 }


 .centeredDiv {
    position: relative;
    top: 40em;
 }

 .headerStyles {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
 }

 .imageStyles {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1; // appear in the background only, with text overlaying it.
 }
```

The center div is wrapped in a larger div:

**HTML**

```
 <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="centeredDiv">
               <div class="headerStyles">Some Text</div>
               <img src="image.png" class="imageStyles">
        </div>
 </div>
```

Every time I try to print, the styling differs between datasets. It...makes little sense to me. The font size in particular seems to change when I print with longer text (yet still one line) than with shorter text.

The placement of the div (based on the top parameter in centeredDiv) also seems to vary in how much from the top it prints.

I'm mostly testing with printing to PDF. In the end, I'd like to be able to create a working/consistent copy that prints similarly in PDF and paper. And cross browser compatible...but right now, I'm mostly concerned with Firefox.

Any leads/insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're probably running into the print settings zooming to fit the width to the page.  I've run into this MANY times.

Comment: Best suggestion from ME, set a fixed width in the outer DIV in the `print` media that will keep it from zooming.

Comment: That sounds quite possible. I'll give that a try.

Comment: In css there is no class but the elements, change imageStyles  to .imageStyles  and rest of the classes

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. I have it correctly written in CSS.

Comment: @rfornal is there a known width/height that is guaranteed to be similar to width: 100%; height: 100%, assuming printing on a standard 8.5in X 11in sheet of paper and default printer settings?

Comment: There may be ... I am just in the process of working on this.  I've been using 1000px width and ajusting for that print and I think that's setting the zoom at 60%. So, my assumption (untested) would be about 640/650px.  This can be off based on margins ... we default to 0.5 inch here.

Comment: I just looked ... at 7.5 inches, assuming 0.5 inch left and right margin, it would be **562px** ... this assumes 75dpi.

Comment: Thanks rfornal, I think my print settings have a higher default DPI. the values I've tested are upward of 1000px. I guess I'll have to play around with it. I had thought of trying this route, but was afraid it'd be even less consistent than using 100%. I might just settle with a number "close enough" and try to center the div on the page instead of starting at top:0; left:0. =/

Comment: printing to PDF defaults to 1200 DPI. ...printer setting defaults to 75 dpi too...sigh. I don't think there's an easy way to support both...